# xamarin.forms - Application.Current.Properties getting cleared after closing app

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am using Application.Current.Properties to store data in android app. Its working fine till app is live. I have exit button to exit from app. When I manually close (sliding app) and return back in app then there is no issue. But when I am closing app using exit button first time then Application.Current.Properties getting cleared.

Setting value

`Application.Current.Properties["currentUser"] = response;`

Exit button code 1

`System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().CloseMainWindow();`

Exit button code 2

`System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill();`

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using [Xamarin.Essentials, secure storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/secure-storage?context=xamarin%2Fxamarin-forms&tabs=android), it will save in the respective native APIs, using SharedPreferences in Android and KeyChain on iOS
If you close your application, the data will remain saved. Only will be destroyed after uninstalling the application.

To save a value:

```
try
{
  await SecureStorage.SetAsync("oauth_token", "secret-oauth-token-value");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  // Possible that device doesn't support secure storage on device.
}
```

To retrieve:

```
try
{
  var oauthToken = await SecureStorage.GetAsync("oauth_token");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  // Possible that device doesn't support secure storage on device.
}
```